# Fast way to iterate over large amount of words in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I wrote a program that should check a dictionary that contains about 50.000 other dictionaries. In those dicts one of the keys has a list of words as value. Now I want to iterate over those words finding the words most similar to some query. However it takes quite a while for it to finish. How can I speed up this process?

```
import pickle,sys

def levenshtein_distance(first, second):
        if first == second: return 0
        elif len(first) == 0: return len(second)
        elif len(second) == 0: return len(first)
        v0 = [None] * (len(second) + 1)
        v1 = [None] * (len(second) + 1)
        for i in range(len(v0)):
            v0[i] = i
        for i in range(len(first)):
            v1[0] = i + 1
            for j in range(len(second)):
                cost = 0 if first[i] == second[j] else 1
                v1[j + 1] = min(v1[j] + 1, v0[j + 1] + 1, v0[j] + cost)
            for j in range(len(v0)):
                v0[j] = v1[j]

        return v1[len(second)]

def remove_duplicates(seq):
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    return [ x for x in seq if not (x in seen or seen_add(x))]

def main():
    dict_pkld = pickle.load(open('woordjes2.pkl', 'rb'))
    postlist = pickle.load(open('postlist.pkl', 'rb'))
    lowest_distance = []
    words = []
    f = sys.stdin.readlines()
    for line in f:
            woorden = line.rstrip()
            query1 = woorden
            print ('Uw query is: "' + query1 + '"')
            print ('Een woord wat hier op lijkt is: \n')
            for sub in dict_pkld.values():
                    woorden = sub['termen']
                    if not query1 in woorden:
                            for woord in woorden:
                                    x = levenshtein_distance(query1, woord)
                                    temp_list_number = []
                                    temp_list_word = []
                                    if lowest_distance:
                                            for number, word in zip(lowest_distance, words):
                                                    if number > x:
                                                            #print ('x is kleiner')
                                                            loc = lowest_distance.index(number)
                                                            lowest_distance[loc] = x
                                                            words[loc] = woord
                                                    elif number == x:
                                                            #print ('x is gelijk')
                                                            temp_list_number.append(x)
                                                            temp_list_word.append(woord)
                                                    else:
                                                            #print ('Niks')
                                                            pass
                                    else:
                                            #print ('lijst is leeg')
                                            lowest_distance.append(x)
                                            words.append(woord)
                                    for item, woordje in zip(temp_list_number, temp_list_word):
                                            if not woordje in words:
                                                    lowest_distance.append(item)
                                                    words.append(woordje)


                    else:
                            pass

            words_new = remove_duplicates(words)
            for woordje in words_new:
                    print ('-' + woordje)
            print ('\nDeze woorden hebben een Levenshtein afstand van ' + str(lowest_distance[0]))

            print ('\nWe zoeken nu naar tweets die het eerste woord in deze lijst bevatten: \n')
            result = postlist[words_new[0]]
            for r in result:
                    print (dict_pkld[r]['tekst'] + '\n')


main()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is `\\Check if word is similar.`?

Comment: No way to answer unless you show all your code. This is more of an outline.

Comment: The rest of the algorithm would probably help finding the right solution. How do you check that the words are similar?

Comment: Just added entire code

Comment: So, if this code works and you want it reviewed, try Code Review instead of Stack Overflow. If it were me I would have loaded it all up into Solr and not written custom code.

Comment: This question could be suitable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), as long as (a) your code works as intended, (b) your code is real code, rather than example code, and (c) your code is included in the body of the question. If you wish for a peer review to improve all aspects of your code, please post it on Code Review.

Comment: Yes it does work.. but the code is very slow. And I can't find a way to speed things up, and that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Allright I will post it there. Thanks for the advice.